# How can I rename selected fields in a Laravel collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I'm going to be importing a number of Excel spreadsheets into a Laravel project using the [Maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) package. That package gives me the data from each spreadsheet as a "[Row Collection](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/2.1/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Collections/RowCollection.php)" which extends the [Illuminate Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) (but does *not* extend the [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) or [Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models)). I then want to save the rows to a table using a Model.

Some spreadsheets will have columns given_nm and family_nm (note the abbreviation on 'name'), some will have first_name and last_name, and there are two or three other variations (all known in advance). Most spreadsheets will have multiple rows, most will have less than a hundred rows but some may have a few thousand rows.

The rows all need to end up in the database as given_name and family_name. So I want to rename the columns 'given_nm' and 'first_name' to 'given_name', and the columns 'family_nm' and 'last_name' to 'family_name', etc, before inserting the collection in to the database.

So ... is there any clean way to change the entire collection, in one action? Or do I need to loop through every record in the collection, doing a [combine()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-combine) on each row to rename the columns?

Thanks.

PS - I'm currently using Laravel 5.1 but would happily upgrade to 5.4 (or even 5.5 when that comes out) if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to loop through it, add the columns you want, and delete those you don't.

```
$collection = $collection->each(function($item, $key){
    $item->given_name = $item->given_nm;
});

//when you are done, delete the unwanted columns
$collection->forget('given_nm');
```